Solving the system $x^4+y^4+z^4=a$, $xy+xz+yz=b$, $xyz=c$
I am trying to solve the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases} x^4+y^4+z^4=a\\[4pt] xy+xz+yz=b\\[4pt] xyz=c\end{cases} 
$$
where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants and $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the variables that need to be solved.
The approach that appears to be the most promising is to isolate for 1 variable in equation 3, substitute it into equations 1 and 2, then do something with the substituted equations 1 and 2 (now in 2 variables) that results in an equation in 1 variable (likely a cubic in $variable^4$) which can then be solved. However, I have messed around with this for a long time and could not find a solution.
Is this system even solvable at all? If so, how can it be done?

Yes, one can solve it!

Let us denote $p = x+y+z$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
a &= x^4+y^4+z^4 := \sum_{ \text{sym}}x^4\\
&=\left(\sum_{ \text{sym}}x^2\right)^2 -2\sum_{ \text{sym}}x^2y^2\\
&=\left(\left(\sum_{ \text{sym}}x\right)^2 - 2\sum_{ \text{sym}}xy\right)^2 - 2\left(\left(\sum_{ \text{sym}}xy\right)^2 - 2xyz\sum_{ \text{sym}}x \right)\\
\color{red}{a}&\color{red}{=(p^2-2b)^2-2(b^2-2cp)} \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
$(1)$ is a quartic equation of $p$ and can be solved analytically. Depending on the value of $(a,b,c)$, this equation can have $2,4$ or no roots.
After determining $p$, $(x,y,z)$ is the solution of the cubic equation $(2)$ which can be solved analytically
$$\color{red}{z^3-pz^2+bz-c = 0}\tag{2}$$
For information, the equation $(2)$ has solution if and only if
$$-27c^2 + 18 pbc - 4 b^3 - 4 p^3 c + p^2 b^2 \ge 0 \tag{1}$$

How to get eq. (2)?
$$(\zeta-x)(\zeta-y)(\zeta-z)=\zeta^3-(x+y+z)\cdot\zeta^2+(x y+x z+y z)\cdot\zeta-x y z=\zeta^3-p\cdot\zeta^2+b\cdot\zeta-c=0$$

We isolate variable $z$ from equation 3.
$$z=\frac{c}{x\cdot y}$$
Then we obtain from equation 2:
$$\frac{c}{x}+\frac{c}{y}+x y=b$$
with the solution
$$y=\frac{\pm\sqrt{(c-b x)^2-4 c x^3}+b x-c}{2 x^2}$$
Hence equation 1 evaluates to
$$\frac{16 c^4 x^4}{\left(-\sqrt{(c-b x)^2-4 c x^3}+b x-c\right)^4}+\frac{\left(-\sqrt{(c-b x)^2-4 c x^3}+b x-c\right)^4}{16 x^8}+x^4=a$$
With the solution for $x$ as roots of equation
$$x^{12}-a x^8+2 c^2 x^6 -4 b^2 c x^5 +\left(b^4+8 b c^2\right) x^4 +\left(-4 b^3 c-4 c^3\right) x^3 +6 b^2 c^2 x^2-4 b c^3 x +c^4=0$$
